# Borderless header for a table

Tags: html, css

What I want to achieve is:

[image: borderless header]

The leftmost header column has no border, but it is a part of the table.

I tried the following HTML:

```
<table class="my-table" style="border-left: 0">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-left: 0;border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0">x</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-left: 0;border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0">f(x)</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

with following CSS:

```
table.my-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
table.my-table td {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/96vk704s/

But upper and lower borders for column 1 are still there.

[image: not quite borderless]

I know I can make a workaround using two tables with absolute sizes, but maybe there is nice way to do it in one table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the border on the `table` and it works

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/96vk704s/1/)

```
table.my-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove table's border, as you are giving border to `table.my-table td` it will wrap all sides of all `td` therefore no need to give border to `table`

```
table.my-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```css
table.my-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.my-table td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="my-table" style="border-left: 0">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-left: 0;border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0">x</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-left: 0;border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0">f(x)</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table class="my-table" style="border:none;">
<tr>
    <td style="border:none;">x</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border:none;">f(x)</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>9</td>
</tr>
```

Just Change your html to this. You just removed borders of **td** , should even remove border for **table** you can achive by doing this.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96vk704s/6/)

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
table.my-table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.my-table td {
 border: 1px solid grey;
 padding: 0 0.5em;
 text-align: center;
}
tr > :first-child{
 border:none !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="my-table">
 <tr>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>f(x)</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>9</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```